# packing spheroids/ellipsoids

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics

I am thinking about a problem I'm trying to formulate, from a mathematical analysis viewpoint. Suppose that you have a finite region in 3-space, and you want to populate it with spheroids or even ellipsoids. I would like to estimate the volume of the sub-region occupied by the spheroids/ellipsoids.

I need some ideas about how to set up this type of problem, ideally from the vantage point of:

1. mathematical analysis
2. fluid mechanics (?)
3. multivariable calculus (?)

Any references are especially welcome!

Comment: Are the spheres / ellipsoids all the same size?

Comment: Are the ellipsoids allowed to touch on an infinite set of points?

Comment: Let's assume that the spheroids/ellipsoids are of uniform size. Of course, later on I'll want to look at situations in which they are of different sizes. The ellipsoids can touch on any number of points, I suppose.